# What does %-8.8s mean when formatting? And can you explain this date formatting %1$tY%1$tm%1$td?

Tags: java, formatting

I get the '-' is the left align but what is the period('.') in between?

I'm also seeing a lot of #impliedDecimal7SignLastTwoZero. 
I read that "Implied decimal simply means there is a decimal point implied at a specified location in a field, but not actually present in the file", but I dont get the "7SignLastTwoZero" portion.

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] of your code for context?

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)?

Comment: The dot separates the field width from the precision. In this case a precision of 8 causes the string to be truncated to 8 chars if it is longer. The second formatting string prints year, month and day of month from argument 1 to the `format` method. `1$` means the first argument. `t` means date and/or time, and `Y`, `m` and `d` the different parts of a date.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt 
<value> reportingStudentId, %-8.8s </value>
The requirements are: 
Unique 8 digit school ID for reporting the student's information.
Alphanumeric, Length: 8

I don't understand the period. Why isnt it %-8s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### %-8.8s

To get a first understanding let’s try it out:

```
    System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "<%-8.8s>%n", "12345678");
    System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "<%-8.8s>%n", "12345");
    System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "<%-8.8s>%n", "123456789012");
```

Output is:

> ```
> <12345678>
> <12345   >
> <12345678>
> ```

As you said `%-8s` would print output left-justified in 8 positions. Except: if the output is longer than 8 chars, it is printed in as many positions as needed. This is where the extra `.8` makes a difference: it truncates the output to at most 8 positions as you see in the third line above. It’s in the documentation:

> The format specifiers for general, character, and numeric types have
>   the following syntax:
>
> ```
>   %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion
> ```
>
> …
>
> The optional *precision* is a non-negative decimal integer usually
>   used to restrict the number of characters. The specific behavior
>   depends on the conversion.
>
> …
>
> **Precision**
>
> For general argument types, the precision is the maximum number of
>   characters to be written to the output.

You added:

> The requirements are: Unique 8 digit school ID for reporting the
>   student's information. Alphanumeric, Length: 8

In this case I’d warn against `%-8.8s`. If by some mistake there is a 9 or 10 digit ID, no one will discover because the formatting tacitly truncates to 8 digits. Better to either print all the digits so we can see them, or report an error in some way.

### %1$tY%1$tm%1$td

```
    System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "%1$tY%1$tm%1$td%n",
                        LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Kirov")));
```

> 20200129

This format string prints year, month and day of month from argument 1 to the format method. `1$` means the first argument after the format string. `t` means date and/or time, and `Y`, `m` and `d` the different parts of a date. So the output meant year 2020, January 29. All of this too is documented:

> The optional *argument_index* is a decimal integer indicating the
>   position of the argument in the argument list. The first argument is
>   referenced by "1$", the second by "2$", etc.
>
> …
>
> ```
> Conversion  Argument Category  Description
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> 't', 'T'    date/time          Prefix for date and time conversion characters.
>                                See Date/Time Conversions.
> ```
>
> …
>
> The following conversion characters are used for formatting dates:
>
> ```
>     'Y'   Year, formatted as at least four digits with leading zeros as necessary, e.g. 0092 equals 92 CE for the Gregorian calendar.
>     'm'   Month, formatted as two digits with leading zeros as necessary, i.e. 01 - 13.
>     'd'   Day of month, formatted as two digits with leading zeros as necessary, i.e. 01 - 31
> ```

I have quoted only the 3 relevant entries from the last table, there are many more letters.

Edit: BTW it may be clearer to obtain the latter result in this way:

```
    System.out.println(LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Europe/Kirov"))
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE));
```

Midnight has passed in Kirov since I first posted this answer, so now the output us:

> 20200130

### Documentation link

[Documentation of Java format strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)